# meaning of "There is not much glory in it"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

What does mean "There is not much glory in it" in the following sentences?:

> Well, it's nothing to do with the party and I'm sure there are more
>   exciting ways that you could spend your time. But we do need some help
>   with something. We’re compiling a database of articles the
>   anthropology faculty has published. **There is not much glory in it**,
>   but we are looking for someone with some knowledge of anthropology who
>   can enter the articles. I hesitate to mention it.

Comment: Have you looked for 'glory' in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `There is not much glory in it` isn't really using `glory` with it's dictionary definition.
Glory technically means `high renown or honor won by notable achievements` according to the Google Dictionary Thing. However, the whole phrase can mean that the thing in question could be boring or somewhat uninteresting.

It could also mean that the thing in question is not very rewarding or interesting compared to other things, which I believe is the right answer in this case. See the examples below for this use.

> Today addiction medicine is an urgently needed specialty, but there **is not much glory in it** compared to other areas of medical work. Taken from [here](https://palmhealthcare.com/5-america-overcome-opioid-epidemic/)

Here, work in addiction medicine isn't necessarily less honorable, but is just less interesting than other medical work.

> "For the worker you got to do your job all the time and there **is not much glory in it**"

Here, the worker's job is being described as less interesting than it otherwise might be. Taken from [here](https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/cycling/2018/07/16/cyclings-servants-do-the-dirty-work-at-tour-de-france/36899269/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the articles published by the anthropology faculty. A small group (assuming) is compiling a database for anthropology based articles. When the author says **"There is not much glory in it"** implying that the database compilation must have entered its starting phase and that it didn't have much articles and information within it, to be [glorified](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glory) or/to be admired by or to be used by people as it wasn't yet completed. They were searching for someone with some knowledge of anthropology who can speed up the processes by entering articles.

Comment: The text is not talking about the glory in the articles but the glory in compiling the database.